# Removing Specific Lines From Contents of a Memo field

Tags: database, delphi, paradox

How would I be able to use Delphi to remove data from a memo field that comes after a certain string, for example the data in the database I'm going through it displayed as such:

```
<Data I want to keep>

======= Old Data ========
<line 1>
<line 2>
etc.
```

How could I tell Delphi to remove all data after (and including) the old data line? But not touch the data that I wish to keep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'your big string with ======= Old Data ======== and more';
  I:=Pos('======= Old Data ========',s);
  if I>0 then
    Delete(s, I, MaxInt);
  ShowMessage(s);
```

Comment: +1 A quicker solution might be `if I > 0 then SetLength(s, I - 1);`, though. At the very least, it should be `System.Delete`, especially since the question is about databases. It's easy for someone careless with a `with` statement to make a mistake and delete data (or end up with hard-to-solve for newbie's compiler errors).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
procedure myForm.ClearFromLine(value: string);
var
  i, index: integer;
begin
  index := memo.lines.IndexOf(value);
  if index = -1 then
    Exit;
  memo.lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := memo.lines.count - 1 downto index do
      memo.lines.delete(i);
  finally
    memo.lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but the question was about a memo *field*, not a `TMemo`. :)